# Строка подключения для подхода DataBase First

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework

Как для подхода `DataBase First` правильно прописать строку подключения? т.к. прочитал, что она должна содержать описание метаданных **EDMX** (файлы *.csdl*, *.ssdl*, *.msl*), а при добавлении строки подключения в параметры проекта в файле конфигурации не прописывается ничего про эти файлы.
Их нужно прописывать в файле конфигурации вручную или есть другой способ добавления строки подключения?

Answer (score 3):

Есть подробная инструкция на MSDN о реализации подхода [EntityFramework DataBase First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj206878). Если Вы посмотрите видео, то там видно, что строка подключения прописывается в файл конфигурации автоматически во время подключения базы данных (время на видео 1:35).

Вот картинка со строкой подключения, которая будет добавлена в `App.Config`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также советую ознакомиться со всем содержимым статьи: [Приступая к работе с платформой Entity Framework (EF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ee712907)